# Why won't the syncplay ai work when i deploy my app via URL?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I've created a Tizen application to play videos using the syncplay api, however when i deploy the application with Tizen studio it works perfectly, but when i deploy it via URL (the wgt is hosted on my server), the synplay api doesn't work.

What am i doing wrong?

Nothing i've tried has made any difference

Comment: Hello, would you share the code related with deploying apps via URL and privilege configuration in config.xml fiel?